# download file to Library/cashes in ios 8 gives bug

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8

i did application works fine with out errors on ios 7 but on ios 8 when i download file to "Library/cashes" it give me bug any one can help or advise please

this is the code :

```
//show loading


[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(showActivityViewer) toTarget:self withObject:nil];


//start download


NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[
                                                     NSURL URLWithString:pdfUrl]];


// Store the Data locally as PDF File
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[
                                                          [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]
                                                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/caches"
                                                          ]];

NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath
                  stringByAppendingPathComponent:variableName];
[pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];


[self.loading stopAnimating];



NSString *phrase = nil; // Document password (for unlocking most encrypted PDF files)
ReaderDocument *document = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:filePath password:phrase];

if (document != nil) // Must have a valid ReaderDocument object in order to proceed with things
{
    ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc] initWithReaderDocument:document];

    readerViewController.delegate = self; // Set the ReaderViewController delegate to self

#if (DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH == TRUE)

                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];

#else // present in a modal view controller

                    readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
                    readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

                    [self presentViewController:readerViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];

#endif // DEMO_VIEW_CONTROLLER_PUSH
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not get the path by getting the mainbundle and just adding the `Library/caches`. 
The proper way is is to use the [`NSFileManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *cachesURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory
                                                          inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                                 appropriateForURL:nil
                                                            create:NO
                                                             error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you i solved with replace the mainbundle line code with this and it work fine on all ios versions

```
NSString *path = nil;
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                                     NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                if ([paths count])
                {
                    NSString *bundleName =
                    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
                    path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:bundleName];
                }
```